# ORDER BY condition then the rest

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

In order to have a trending list of `models` table, I use a query which group the occurrences of `model_id` in `medias` table from the last 30 days.

```
SELECT models.*,medias.model_id, COUNT(model_id) AS OCCURENCE
FROM medias
JOIN models ON models.id = medias.model_id
WHERE medias.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY medias.model_id
ORDER BY OCCURENCE DESC
LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$offset
```

However, in this query, I would like to find a way to add the rest of `models` table  in a way that it will returns the trending list of the last 30 days followed by the trending list of all time.

```
WHERE medias.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) ---> Then Infinite
```

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't make any sense to me.  I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL - which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I use mySQL ...

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you wanted to build on your existing query, which lists data by occurrence in the last 30 days, by adding a further set of results that aren't date limited.

The following query can be seen working in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f522b/1).  The fiddle uses an arbitrary dataset, as you've not specified much about that.

```
SELECT 
  models.*,medias.model_id, COUNT(model_id) AS occurance, 1 as orderfield
 FROM medias
  JOIN models ON models.id = medias.model_id
 WHERE medias.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
 GROUP BY medias.model_id
UNION
SELECT
  models.*,medias.model_id, COUNT(model_id) AS occurance, 2 as orderfield
 FROM medias
  JOIN models ON models.id = medias.model_id
 GROUP BY medias.model_id
 ORDER BY orderfield, occurance DESC;
```

That will follow your original query with a results set that does just as described above.  I've used an identifier with each query so that they can be ordered with the "30 days" results first, which is just a quick and dirty way to get this working.

If you wanted the 2nd set to not include the data in the first set, you'd just need to use this `where` clause in the 2nd query:

```
WHERE medias.date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

As shown in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f522b/2).

Obviously you'll have to put your php values back in to limit/offset the results - I've left them out for demonstration purposes.

If that's not what you're trying to achieve, you might need to edit your question to be more specific.